# Force Windows 7 to prefer its own Microsoft MJPG codec for MJPG files?

Tags: codec, quicktime, mjpeg, ffdshow

I'm installing a system with Windows 7 x64.
This system needs to be able to play .AVI files encoded with the Mjpeg codec ("MJPG")

I've noticed that "out of the box", Windows can play these files just fine.
But after I install Quicktime 7, which I need to install for other reasons, MJPG playback of AVI files has issues (inverted fields and black levels lifted) Not just in Quicktime Player but in Windows Media Player, Adobe applications, etc etc.

It turns out Quicktime installs its own MJPG codec onto the system, and apparently that codec has issues. I've tried other versions of Quicktime 7, I've tried K-Lite and XP Codec Packs, I've tried ffdshow/Lav separately, together, etc etc. I've tried installing 3rd party MJPG codecs like Mainconcept. Nothing solves the problem except uninstalling Quicktime. But as I said, I need it.

What I'd like to do is force Windows to use its own MJPG decompressor, since that one works fine. That would be the cleanest, simplest solution, and this is a work computer that I want to keep as clean as possible. So -- is there a way to edit the registry or otherwise tell Windows - use your own MJPG codec, at all times, in all players, in all applications. Never use the one that was installed by Apple?

I'm fine to mess with the registry or otherwise hack the system if that's the price to pay, but I don't know any tools that can help manually tweak this sort of thing. I need to know where to start.

Thanks to anybody who can help -
K